# Не загружается карта (OSM) в QML под Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, openstreetmap

Сразу скажу, что на PC все загружается и работает.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtLocation/QLocation>

#include "mydevice.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Описание карты в QML файле (псевдокод):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtLocation 5.3

Plugin
{
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm"
    PluginParameter { name: "osm.useragent"; value: "myapp" }

Map
{
    id: map

    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    //activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[6]

    center
    {
        latitude:  56.32867
        longitude: 44.00205
    }
    zoomLevel: 12

    MapCircle
    {
        center
        {
            latitude:   56.32867
            longitude: 44.00205
        }
        radius: 500.0
        border.width: 1
    }
}
```

В AndroidManifest 3 activity:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
```

Компилирую из-под ArchLinux, Qt 5.8, QtCreator 4.3.0. SDK, JDK, NDK, Ant указаны.

Вывод приложения показать не могу т.к. почему то при запуске любого QML приложения с помощью AVD оно показывает белый экран и в выводе пишет про всяческие ошибки. На реальном устройстве приложение запускается без ошибок, все кроме карты отрисовывает, но карту не загружает. Я пробовал запустить пример приложения карты ("Map Viewer (QML)"), там тоже изначально ничего не загружается НО если выбрать любой тип карты кроме стандартной ("Street") то все грузится. Пытался сделать тот же тип карты, который грузится в примере, но все равно также: на компе работает, на Androidе нет.

---

На Qt 5.9 все заработало......